# Rsync --backup-dir seems to be ignored

Tags: rsync

I want to use rsync to backup a directory from a local location to a remote location, and store changed files in another remote location. I did use:

```
rsync -rcvhL --progress --backup --backup-dir=user@url.com:/home/user/Changes/`date +%Y.%m.%d` . user@url.com:/home/user/Files/
```

The --backup-dir stays empty, while it should be filled. Is it possible what I try to accomplish, and am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some restrictions on `--backup-dir`. See the manual page.
The main points:

- The destination directory and the backup directory must be on the same machine. The manual call it "the receiving side".
- If an rsync daemon is the receiver, the backup dir cannot go outside  the  module's path hierarchy.

Comment: what is a *module's path hierarchy*?

Comment: @Abdull In `rsyncd.conf` you can define *modules*, which are the way that rsyncd makes part of the filesystem available. Each module has a path. Say I define the module `[local]` with the path `/usr/local`. Using `[local]` you can write to e.g. `/usr/local/bin`, but not to `/usr/bin`.